# Tips on optimizing DP solution further

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I solved the Longest Increasing Subsequence question on LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/

> Given an unsorted array of integers, find the length of longest increasing subsequence.  For `[10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]`, the answer is `4` (size of `[2,3,7,101]`).

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int helper(vector<int>& nums, unordered_map<int, vector<int>>& dp, int lastNum, int startIndex) {
        if(startIndex>=nums.size()) return 0;
        if(dp.find(lastNum)!=dp.end() && dp[lastNum].size()>=startIndex && dp[lastNum][startIndex]!=INT_MIN) {
            return dp[lastNum][startIndex];
        }
        
        int ans=0;
        if(nums[startIndex]>lastNum) ans=1+helper(nums, dp, nums[startIndex], startIndex+1);
        ans=max(ans, helper(nums, dp, lastNum, startIndex+1));
        
        return dp[lastNum][startIndex]=ans;
    }
    
    int lengthOfLIS(vector<int>& nums) {
        int ans=0;
        unordered_map<int, vector<int>> dp;
        dp[INT_MIN].resize(10001, INT_MIN);
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) dp[nums[i]].resize(10001, INT_MIN);
        
        return helper(nums, dp, INT_MIN, 0);
    }
};
```

Note that I am also memoizing it, using the `dp` table above and using two states `lastNum` (`nums[i]` value that we picked in the last recursion) and `startIndex`.  In the [solution section](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/solution/) they use two states `prev` (*index*, unlike the *value* that I pass using `lastNum`) and `curpos` (analogous to `startIndex`).

I am confused because I still get a TLE.  Now I am aware that the time limits set by the online judges are arbitrary, but I am looking to see why using `lastNum` instead of `prev` as a state results in more execution time.  Similarly, are there any other optimizations that I can make?

Thanks!

Edit: I changed it to `10001`, based on Igor's suggestion in the comments, all the tests cases pass now, but it takes a lot of time:

> 24 / 24 test cases passed, but took too long.

Edit2: Said differently, I guess my question is, as an interviewer what advice would one provide to nudge the candidate in the right direction (of using `prev` instead of `lastNum`)?

Comment: 10000001 squared is around 100GB. Just allocating that much RAM would take forever, if it succeeds at all.

Comment: Oh, why do you square it?

Comment: Because you allocate vectors of 10000001 elements in a loop, which presumably may run for up to 10000001 iterations.

Comment: On changing that to `10001`, I still get `24 / 24 test cases passed, but took too long.`

Comment: Okay, I get it now.  Can you suggest some other way to memoize it?  Perhaps using something other than `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your solution, but I'm a bit puzzled here: `dp[INT_MIN].resize(10000001, INT_MIN);`, maybe your solution is not O(N). This'd get accepted:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Solution {
    static const inline int lengthOfLIS(const std::vector<int> &nums) {
        std::vector<int> longest;

        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < nums.size(); index++) {
            const auto iter = std::lower_bound(longest.begin(), longest.end(), nums[index]);

            if (iter == longest.end()) {
                longest.emplace_back(nums[index]);

            } else {
                *iter = nums[index];
            }
        }

        return longest.size();
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, my focus right now is on trying to improve my answer and in order to do that, I seek to realize where I am making a mistake.  I know the Discussion Board has many solutions (almost all better than mine), but those aren't mine; and I need to understand what I am doing wrong, so that I won't repeat that mistake in an interview.

Comment: Your "mistake" is in using an algorithm which is inherently too slow.

Comment: `lastNum` and `startIndex` are being used to implement the wrong algorithm.